# Update Claims to Principal after Token Validation

Tags: owin, openid, jwt

I have API which makes use of JWTBearerAuthentication. Everything works fine from Authentication perspective. However there is a need to update the Claims on the principal after the validation is complete. There are some information which I have to derive instead of receiving from source (token) claims. I was thinking if there is a way  that after the validation is successful I can add some claims to existing claims identity/ principal to perform some access rights stuff. Below is the sample code in my start up class.

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenHandler = new ValidateJwtSecurityTokenHandlerforLogs(_loggingService, _environment),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name, 
                    RoleClaimType = OpenIDConfiguration.Permission, 
                    ValidateAudience = false, 
                    ValidIssuer = authority,
                    
                    
                    IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                    {
                        var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
                    }
                }
                
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to modify the claims after authentication:

One option is

```
 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            // Token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.
            context.Principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("VIPCustomer", "YES"));
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
};
```

To enable more advanced claims transformation scenarios, we can add a custom transformation class

```
public class BonusLevelClaimTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "bonuslevel"))
        {
            //Lookup bonus level.....
            principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("bonuslevel", "12345"));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Then we register it in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, BonusLevelClaimTransformation>();
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot add the first option to my MVC project. Also second option adds the claim but it doesn't persist them . Not sure if I am missing anything. Do you have any working example where it is integrated.

Comment: Do you use classic ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? my example uses ASP.NET core.